# Tikz-cd arrow tips

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I changed the commutative diagrams in a LaTeX document from xypic to tikz-cd.  I must add that I also have some tikz diagrams with arrows (for example, Dynkin diagrams). Initially I had some problems matching the arrow tips for tikz diagrams and tikz-cd diagrams, but thanks to the comments bellow I was able to fix this.

My question now is how to  globally set the arrow tips to something more agreeable (to me), for example with

```
\tikzset{>=Straight Barb}
```

(I am not sure about the names of the arrow tips)

Following the comments below I was able to get a minimal running example with the CM arrrow tips:

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
%\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}%
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}{f} \arrow[two heads]{d}[swap]{x} & C\arrow[two heads]{d} \\
B \arrow{r}[swap]{g}   &  D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\bigskip

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\draw[red, thick,->] (2,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[thick,-] (2,0) -- (2,1);
\draw[thick,-] (2,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[thick,-] (2,0) -- (2,-1);
\draw[fill=red] (2,0) circle(.02);  
\draw[red, thick,->] (2,0) -- (2.707,0.707);
\draw[red,thick,->] (2,0) -- (2.707,-0.707);
\draw[thick,->] (2,0) -- (1.293,0.707);
\draw[thick,->] (2,0) -- (1.293,-0.707);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That  is not code for tikz-cd diagrams, and please make your example complete

Comment: In addition to tikz-cd diagrams I use tikz to draw root diagrams and Dynkin diagrams. My document compiles correctly except for the tikz diagrams. I made some edits to the post to clarify this.

Comment: As mention please complete your code to make something others can just copy and test. Please remove irrelevant packages. Unrelated: there is no need to add and driver to graphicx it has handled that for years. Plus drop latexsym it uses an entire math alphabet for 9 symbols you don't use anyways

Comment: I made some edits. I had the list of packages that I thought might be conflicting.  In the edit I deleted some whose relevance is questionable. I understand that people in this forum may be users whose work is not in edition (that is my case) and my question is for suggestions on a specific topic. The code for the example is complete and compiles if I leave out the package that I mention in the post.

Comment: The code you provided is not complete, there is no document class. Also it is split into two parts, there is no reason for that. Have a look at other questions to see what I mean

Comment: I added the document class. I do not see the splitting, just the comment-out package. I have seen other posts and I will leave mine as it is, perhaps another user may have a suggestion. @daleif thanks for your comments and for trying to help. Let us leave the comments for now since I don't want to move to chat.

Comment: What we would like to see is a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927), not only your preamble. So, some compilable code that shows your problem and that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. I don't get an error using the preamble and the code you placed above it. That said, you can style the arrows in `tikz-cd` environments with `\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, every arrow/.append style={red, thick}}` for example.

Comment: Wouldn't what you're looking for be `\tikzcdset{arrows=-stealth}`?

Comment: @Jasper Habicht, I have a running example now and I think I may have pinpointed my initial problem. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Bernard I think I fixed the problem with tikz-cd matching the arrows now with the ones with the tikz diagrams. Now I just need to learn how to select the arrow tips for the whole document. I am reading the tikz manuals but they are a bit unfriendly.

Comment: I confess it's one of the reasons why I prefer doing things with `pstricks`.

Comment: My migration from xypic to tikz diagrams has been rather bumpy. But I use tikz in my presentations with beamer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you after the following:

[image]

For changing arrows' heads in `tikz-cd` diagrams you need to define something like this (for global settings in document's preamble):

```
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }
```

For similar changes in `tikzpicture`s, you need to define them by `\tikzset` in document preamble for global settings or put its in `tikzpicture` options for local settings as is done in following MWE:

```
\documentclass[usenames, dvipsnames]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,        
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                matrix}%
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }
           

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tikzcd}
A   \ar[r,"f"]    
    \ar[d,two heads,"x"]    &   C   \ar[d, two heads, "d"]   \\
B   \ar[r,"g"]              &   D
\end{tikzcd}
    \]
\bigskip
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,
  arr/.style = {draw=#1, thick, -Straight Barb},
arr/.default = red
                        ]
\draw[arr]  (2,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[thick]    (2,1) -- (2,-1)
                (2,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[arr]  (2,0) -- (2.707,0.707);
\draw[arr]  (2,0) -- (2.707,-0.707);
\draw[arr=black] (2,0) -- (1.293,0.707);
\draw[arr=black] (2,0) -- (1.293,-0.707);
\fill[red]  (2,0) circle[radius=1mm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

Defining of type of the arrows' heads can be global (with style definitions in documents' preambles, or local, if they are part of figures. An example of combination of the global and local settings is present in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[usenames, dvipsnames]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,        
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                matrix}%
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
           }    % global setting for arrow heads in tikz-cd diagrams
\tikzset{>=Straight Barb
           }    % global settings for arrow heads in tikzpicturres
           

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tikzcd}
A   \ar[r,"f"]    
    \ar[d,two heads,"x"]    &   C   \ar[d, two heads, "d"]   \\
B   \ar[r,"g"]              &   D
\end{tikzcd}
    \]
\bigskip
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
% local settings use global and if needed overwrite global one
       scale = 1.2,
  arr/.style = {draw=#1, thick, ->}, % for the arrowheads is used global setting  
arr/.default = red
                        ]
\draw[arr]  (2,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[thick]    (2,1) -- (2,-1)
                (2,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[arr]  (2,0) -- (2.707,0.707);
\draw[arr]  (2,0) -- (2.707,-0.707);
\draw[arr=black] (2,0) -- (1.293,0.707);
\draw[arr=black] (2,0) -- (1.293,-0.707);
\fill[red]  (2,0) circle[radius=1mm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: @ Zarko: Thanks, these are the arrow tips I would like in my document. Is there a way to make a global change to the preamble to get all arrows in my document as in your example as I have quite a few tikz diagrams in it? I this global change were possible, even the arrows in formulas like $A\rightarrow B$ would have the same tips. When I put a global declaration as \tikzset{>=latex} the tips change to the old latex ones.

Comment: @FZaldivar, see addendum to my answer and corrected explanation in answer.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.